# IDA pro and unrolled loops

Tags: ida, compilers

Is there a trick in IDA Pro to deal with unrolled loops like in the screenshot below?
[image]

Another, possibly related compiler optimisation is this - instead of loading an offset into a memory area, it does mov for each character (MSVC8). Any quick way to deal with these?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "deal with", but I believe there is a way to combine blocks into a single relabeled one.

Comment: The 'optimisation' is an obfuscation trick, to ensure that the strings in question do not show up in the binary. To find stuff like this requires emulation, either with a homebrewed script or something like the [x86emu](http://www.idabook.com/x86emu/) plugin.

Comment: @DarthGizka not convinced this was done on purpose although it is plausible. There are optimisations like if you had previously resolved InternetOpenA and now want to resolve InternetCrackUrlA, they'd copy only the CrackURLA part. Seems like compiler optimisation got its way.

Comment: @Konrads it's also sometimes used to build PIC. Normally the strings would end up in .rdata but this way (`const char szName[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};`) it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a topic regarding the 2nd question, see [How can I clean up strings built at runtime?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/how-can-i-clean-up-strings-built-at-runtime). Personally I use the script by ASERT script, it works pretty well.

Comment: The ASERT script doesn't really work if you have statements like this: mov     [rsp+138h+var_118], 'k' where this is the first in the sequence :(

Comment: I also now realise there are 2 questions in 1.

Comment: The scripts that work with x64 are from FireEye/FLARE: https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2014/08/flare-ida-pro-script-series-automatic-recovery-of-constructed-strings-in-malware.html