# Handling stack strings in IDA, but with a twist (wchar_t-based, not char-based)

Tags: ida

Consider the following disassembly:

```
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458], 690068h   ; L'i' + L'h'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+4], 2E0064h ; L'.' + L'd'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+8], 6C0064h ; L'l' + L'd'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+0Ch], 6Ch   ; 'l'
; -> L"hid.dll"
```

This is structurally similar to the disassembly [from this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2977/245), except that the characters are `wchar_t` instead of `char` and moved dword-wise instead of byte-wise. The comment on the last `mov` was automatically added by IDA, I had to add the others myself.

The `6Ch` in the last `mov` line could also be treated with <kbd>R</kbd> to change the representation to what's currently shown in the comment.

Not so with the other lines. <kbd>R</kbd> has no effect there, although IDA has no trouble deciphering a dword-wise copy of char-based strings as evidenced in [this blog article](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-88-character-operand-type-and-stack-strings/) (example from there: 70747468h -> 'ptth' -> "http").

I know of the [stackstrings plugin](https://github.com/mandiant/flare-ida), but cannot use it due to its dependency on Python 2.x!

Is there a configuration setting (similar to string types and data carousel) to teach IDA the ability to use <kbd>R</kbd> in these cases to make better sense of those `wchar_t`-based stack strings?

IDA Pro version: latest (7.7.220218)

Comment: The flare stackstrings module hasn't been converted to Python 3 because of a dependency on `vivisect`. From the code: `# currently depending on vivisect, which will never be ported to py3` .. however `vivisect` has been ported to 3 so converting the stackstrings plugin to Python 3 is doable. Ref: https://vivisect.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vivisect/quickstart.html

Comment: I haven't set up for plugin development, but you could give this a try: https://github.com/m3gat0nn4ge/flare-ida/pull/1

Answer (score -1):

The problem was caused by a hex-string in the middle of the wchar_t string!
The stackstrings plugin correctly handles such strings, but IDA does not.

For example, in the following code:
    `mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458], 690068h   ; L'i' + L'h'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+4], 2E0064h ; L'.' + L'd'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+8], 6C0064h ; L'l' + L'd'
mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+0Ch], 6C68h  ; 'lh'
; -> L"hid.dll"`

IDA correctly displays the string as "hid.dll" when the last mov is changed to:
    mov     dword ptr [rbp+430h+var_458+0Ch], 6C6Ch  ; 'll'
; -> L"hid.dll"